# EC2-Image builder failed with Unable to bootstrap TOE

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I am using the `AWS-Ec2 image builder` for the first time and I have configured the pipeline with default configs and I am trying to run a `component` which is `amazon-owned` (python-3-linux), and I get the following error:

> SSM execution 'da233246-f411-8324-9c46-23c23ee4519ae' failed with status = 'Failed' in state = 'BUILDING' and failure message = 'Unable to bootstrap TOE'

And when I looked into the `SSM` automation I see the following output for that step as below:

> Waiting for Cloud-init to initialize ...
> Cloud-init fails to initialize ... waiting another 5 minutes for the instance to stabilize
> /var/lib/amazon/ssm/i-0227a2e739e04bd18/document/orchestration/ee2476f3-3swe-4197-g351-2j4912f2f4123/awsrunShellScript/0.awsrunShellScript/_script.sh: line 49: /tmp/imagebuilder/TaskOrchestratorAndExecutor/bootstrap.sh: No such file or directory
> {"failureMessage":"Unable to bootstrap TOE"}

> ----------ERROR-------
> chmod: cannot access '/tmp/imagebuilder/TaskOrchestratorAndExecutor/bootstrap.sh': No such file or directory
> failed to run commands: exit status 1

Can someone help me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you get permission errors, you may have mounted /tmp with noexec. (This also causes SSM failures)

In your particular case, /tmp may not exist at all.

Try choosing a different location for your working directory in the `workingDirectory` field of the image recipe.

To debug: set `TerminateInstanceOnFailure: false` and add a `KeyPair` so you can log in after it fails.

Comment: In my case, I had to change the `workingDirectory` as I was using CIS hardened image that doesnt allow the scripts to be run from /tmp folder.